# Rapid json parser returns null when it tries to parse '\n' character

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson, jsonparser

My Input string is like this:

```
std::string temp = "{\"key\":\""+ message + "\"}";
```

For Eg: `message` can be like this:

```
"Stack \n Overflow"
```

`message` can be anything. It can contain escape sequence characters also.

I expect this is a valid JSON and if I try to parse that JSON using below code:

```
Document document; 
document.Parse(temp.c_str());
```

`document.parse` is returning null.

I don't want to add one more `\` before escape sequences. I just want to understand if there are any other ways to parse this JSON string using rapid JSON library in C++.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

`document.Parse` returns null when the JSON you pass in to it is not valid. There is no substitute for creating valid JSON, and that means ensuring that the contents of `message` are properly escaped, particularly any `"` characters, control characters like line breaks, etc.  You have to deal with it, not avoid it.

For example

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string jsonEscape(const std::string &s)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for(char c : s)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '"':  oss << "\\\""; break;
            case '\\': oss << "\\\\"; break;
            case '/':  oss << "\\/"; break;
            case '\b': oss << "\\b"; break;
            case '\f': oss << "\\f"; break;
            case '\r': oss << "\\r"; break;
            case '\n': oss << "\\n"; break;
            case '\t': oss << "\\t"; break;
            default:
                if ((c >= 0x00) && (c <= 0x1F))
                    oss << "\\u" << std::hex << std::noshowbase << std::nouppercase << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << (int)c;
                else
                    oss << c;
                break;
        }
    }
    return oss.str();
}
```

```
std::string temp = "{\"key\": \"" + jsonEscape(message) + "\"}";
```

Or, you could simply use RapidJSON's own API to produce a valid JSON string, and to parse it afterwards (which would be redundant, since you would already have a `Document`):

```
Document document(kObjectType);

Value key;
key.SetString(StringRef(message.c_str(), message.length()));
document.AddMember("key", key, document.GetAllocator());

StringBuffer buffer;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
document.Accept(writer);

std::string temp = buffer.GetString();
```